# App crashed with [WAKScrollView canBecomeFocused]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiaccessibility

The app is crashing on iOS 13 versions only with crash details fetched from Firebase Crashlytics.

There are no specific details about the app location where the app is crashing. I have tried finding out about it, but not succeeded.

> Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
>   -[WAKScrollView canBecomeFocused]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x283fc5e80

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x1a534b5f0 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1a506dbcc objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1a524fea8 -[NSOrderedSet initWithSet:copyItems:]
3  CoreFoundation                 0x1a534f694 ___forwarding___
4  CoreFoundation                 0x1a53515bc _CF_forwarding_prep_0
5  UIKitCore                      0x1a8ef0664 _UIFocusItemCanBecomeFocusedAndChildrenAreNotFocused
6  UIKitCore                      0x1a8f12a58 -[_UIFocusItemRegion initWithFrame:item:]
7  WebCore                        0x1dac31288 -[UIKitWebAccessibilityObjectWrapper(UIFocusConformance) _searchForFocusRegionsInContext:]
8  UIKitCore                      0x1a8f28ff4 -[_UIFocusMapSnapshot addRegionsInContainer:]
9  WebCore                        0x1dac311d4 -[UIKitWebAccessibilityObjectWrapper(UIFocusConformance) _searchForFocusRegionsInContext:]
10 UIKitCore                      0x1a8f28ff4 -[_UIFocusMapSnapshot addRegionsInContainer:]
11 UIKitCore                      0x1a9886828 -[UIView _addAccessibilityFocusContainersInRect:inCoordinateSpace:context:]
12 UIKitCore                      0x1a9886504 -[UIView _searchForFocusRegionsInContext:]
13 UIKitCore                      0x1a8f28ff4 -[_UIFocusMapSnapshot addRegionsInContainer:]
14 UIKitCore                      0x1a8f291c4 -[_UIFocusMapSnapshot addRegionsInContainers:]
15 UIKitCore                      0x1a98864e0 -[UIView _searchForFocusRegionsInContext:]
16 UIKitCore                      0x1a8f28ff4 -[_UIFocusMapSnapshot addRegionsInContainer:]
17 UIKitCore                      0x1a8f291c4 -[_UIFocusMapSnapshot addRegionsInContainers:]
18 UIKitCore                      0x1a98864e0 -[UIView _searchForFocusRegionsInContext:]
19 UIKitCore                      0x1a8f28ff4 -[_UIFocusMapSnapshot addRegionsInContainer:]
20 UIKitCore                      0x1a8f291c4 -[_UIFocusMapSnapshot addRegionsInContainers:]
21 UIKitCore                      0x1a98864e0 -[UIView _searchForFocusRegionsInContext:]
22 UIKitCore                      0x1a8f28ff4 -[_UIFocusMapSnapshot addRegionsInContainer:]
23 UIKitCore                      0x1a8f291c4 -[_UIFocusMapSnapshot addRegionsInContainers:]
24 UIKitCore                      0x1a98864e0 -[UIView _searchForFocusRegionsInContext:]
25 UIKitCore                      0x1a8f28ff4 -[_UIFocusMapSnapshot addRegionsInContainer:]
26 UIKitCore                      0x1a8f291c4 -[_UIFocusMapSnapshot addRegionsInContainers:]
27 UIKitCore                      0x1a98864e0 -[UIView _searchForFocusRegionsInContext:]
28 UIKitCore                      0x1a8f28ff4 -[_UIFocusMapSnapshot addRegionsInContainer:]
29 UIKitCore                      0x1a8f291c4 -[_UIFocusMapSnapshot addRegionsInContainers:]
30 UIKitCore                      0x1a98864e0 -[UIView _searchForFocusRegionsInContext:]
31 UIKitCore                      0x1a8f28ff4 -[_UIFocusMapSnapshot addRegionsInContainer:]
32 UIKitCore                      0x1a8f2888c -[_UIFocusMapSnapshot _capture]
33 UIKitCore                      0x1a8f27e38 -[_UIFocusMapSnapshot _initWithSnapshotter:mapArea:searchArea:]
34 UIKitCore                      0x1a8f29f2c -[_UIFocusMapSnapshotter captureSnapshot]
35 UIKitCore                      0x1a8f21754 -[_UIFocusMap _defaultFocusItemInEnvironment:limitScopeUsingFocusPreferences:]
36 UIKitCore                      0x1a8efbd84 -[_UIFocusEnvironmentPreferenceEnumerationContext _inferPreferencesForEnvironment:]
37 UIKitCore                      0x1a8efbb40 -[_UIFocusEnvironmentPreferenceEnumerationContext _resolvePreferredFocusEnvironments]
38 UIKitCore                      0x1a8efba80 -[_UIFocusEnvironmentPreferenceEnumerationContext prefersNothingFocused]
39 UIKitCore                      0x1a8efc550 _enumeratePreferredFocusEnvironments
40 UIKitCore                      0x1a8efc670 _enumeratePreferredFocusEnvironments
41 UIKitCore                      0x1a8efc670 _enumeratePreferredFocusEnvironments
42 UIKitCore                      0x1a8efc670 _enumeratePreferredFocusEnvironments
43 UIKitCore                      0x1a8efc670 _enumeratePreferredFocusEnvironments
44 UIKitCore                      0x1a8efc670 _enumeratePreferredFocusEnvironments
45 UIKitCore                      0x1a8efc670 _enumeratePreferredFocusEnvironments
46 UIKitCore                      0x1a8efc344 -[_UIFocusEnvironmentPreferenceEnumerator enumeratePreferencesForEnvironment:usingBlock:]
47 UIKitCore                      0x1a8efccc4 -[_UIDeepestPreferredEnvironmentSearch deepestPreferredFocusableItemForEnvironment:inFocusSystem:]
48 UIKitCore                      0x1a8f3af68 -[UIFocusUpdateContext _updateDestinationItemIfNeeded]
49 UIKitCore                      0x1a8f3ad48 -[UIFocusUpdateContext _destinationItemInfo]
50 UIKitCore                      0x1a8f3ac30 -[UIFocusUpdateContext nextFocusedItem]
51 UIKitCore                      0x1a8f2b96c -[UIFocusSystem updateFocusIfNeeded]
52 UIKitCore                      0x1a93ff94c _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks
53 UIKitCore                      0x1a93ef2f4 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks
54 UIKitCore                      0x1a941f744 _afterCACommitHandler
55 CoreFoundation                 0x1a52c8fb8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
56 CoreFoundation                 0x1a52c3eac __CFRunLoopDoObservers
57 CoreFoundation                 0x1a52c4328 __CFRunLoopRun
58 CoreFoundation                 0x1a52c3c34 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
59 GraphicsServices               0x1af40d38c GSEventRunModal
60 UIKitCore                      0x1a93f622c UIApplicationMain
61 MagicBox Learning              0x104718058 main + 14 (main.m:14)
62 libdyld.dylib                  0x1a514b800 start
```

Comment: Please add a [example] where you use `WKScrollView` (not `WAKScrollView`).

Comment: Its WAKScrollView which is the Private class of WebKit. I got this log from Firebase Crashlytics. Since the logs are not mentioning any source code line, therefore it's difficult for me give the line of code where I feel that problem is coming.

Comment: @HarshSharma did you found any solution to this I am also facing the same issue

Comment: Can you share the lines of code where you use WAKScrollView, or anything related to it.

Comment: One of my apps had this issue due to YTPlayerView which is used to play youtube videos in the app... Does your app use YTPlayerView?

Comment: any solution ? i had crash to which contains webview

Answer (score 2):

We had this issue in our app if there was a bluetooth keyboard attached to the device, but only if the Settings->Accessibility->Keyboards->Full Keyboard Access setting was enabled.  As soon as that was turned off there were not more crashes.